# Synchronizing custom device log data with AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, embedded, aws-iot

I have an application that requires an approach to ensuring custom defined device logs are synchronized on the AWS IoT cloud. An example of a device data log would be the device's ambient temperature, transmitted to AWS at a 3 minute interval. The logs would be overwritten on the device in rolling fashion with oldest overwritten first. Device logs should not be duplicated or have any missing entries on the AWS side.

My question is: what is the standard approach to achieve this? Is there a specific location/tool on AWS that suits this use case (e.g. Device Shadow)? Does anybody know of an example that implements this, including how I would get logs across? Could and/or should each log type, e.g. temperature, error codes, etc. have its own independent "topic"?

I am unsure of the terminology to use in Google searches in order to find the correct answer to this question.

Thanks.